# Conflicting constraints in Antlr

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to learn antlr. If I am expecting these kind of sentences (first word is uppercase, rest can be multiple alphanumeric mixed case words):

```
HELLO world foo
THIS ThaT FOO
HELLO THAT 
BANANA BeRRY 99
APPLE juice80
```

If I define rules as:

```
grammar Hello;
r: UC MC
UC: [A-Z]+ ; //only uppercase
MC: [A-Z|a-z|0-9]+ ; //uppercase, lowercase, and numbers or anycombination of these
```

For the input HELLO WORLD, I get the **error:**
`mismatched input WORLD expecting MC`

I see that the two rules conflict when it comes to the uppercase characters. How do I handle such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for this grammar would be to create a parser rule that allows both token types:

```
grammar Hello;
r: uc mc;
uc: UC;
mc: UC | MC;
UC: [A-Z]+ ; //only uppercase
MC: [A-Za-z0-9]+ ; //uppercase, lowercase, and numbers or anycombination of these
```

If you want that the tokens are correctly lexed you will have to influence the lexer to switch the lexing mode.